# How to store an array of values into a variable

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a function which carries out complex load balancing, and I need to first find out the list of idle servers. After that, I have to iterate over a subset of that list, and finally I have to do a lot of complex things, so I don't want to constantly query the list over and over again. See the below as an example (Note that this is PSUEDO CODE ONLY).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_balance (p_company_id BIGINT, p_num_min_idle_servers BIGINT)
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
DECLARE
    v_idle_server_ids BIGINT [];
    v_num_idle_servers BIGINT;
    v_num_idle_servers_to_retire BIGINT;

BEGIN
    PERFORM * FROM server FOR UPDATE;

    SELECT
        count(server.id)
    INTO
        v_num_idle_servers
    WHERE
        server.company_id=p_company_id
    AND
        server.connection_count=0
    AND
        server.state = 'up';

    v_num_idle_servers_to_retire = v_num_idle_servers - p_num_min_idle_servers;

    SELECT
        server.id
    INTO
        v_idle_server_ids
    WHERE
        server.company_id=p_company_id
    AND
        server.connection_count=0
    AND
        server.state = 'up'
    ORDER BY
        server.id;

    FOR i in 1..v_num_idle_servers_to_retire
        UPDATE
            server
        SET
            state = 'down'
        WHERE
            server.id = v_idle_server_ids[i];
```

**Question:** I was thinking of getting the list of servers and looping over them one by one. Is this possible in postgres?

**Note:** I tried putting it all in one single query but it gets very, VERY complicated as there are multiple joins and subqueries. For example, a system but have three applications running on three different servers, where the applications know their load but the servers know their company affiliation, so I would need to join the system to the applications and the applications to the servers

Comment: In any number of ways [Loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I guess my question is then "*how do I store returned primary keys into a variable and then use that variable in a loop to accomplish my goal*"

Comment: Assuming you mean `v_idle_server_ids BIGINT []` then `SELECT array_agg(server_id) INTO v_idle_server_ids ...` .  See [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html). Then `LOOP` over array [array loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb: if you're looping in SQL there's probably a better way.

You want to `set state = 'down'` until you have a certain number of idle servers.

We can do this in a single statement. Use a [Common Table Expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to query your idle servers and feed that to an `update from`. If you do this a lot you can turn the CTE into a view.

But we need to limit how many we take down based on how many idle servers there are. We can do that with a limit. But `update from` doesn't take a limit, so we need a second CTE to limit the results.

Here I've hard coded company_id 1 and p_num_min_idle_servers 2.

```
with idle_servers as (
  select id
  from server
  where server.company_id=1
    and connection_count=0
    and state = 'up'
),
idle_servers_to_take_down as (
  select id
  from idle_servers
  -- limit doesn't work in update from
  limit (select count(*) - 2 from idle_servers)
)
update server
set state = 'down'
from idle_servers_to_take_down
where server.id = idle_servers_to_take_down.id
```

This has the advantage of being done in one statement avoiding race conditions without having to lock the whole table.

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d783c721b811b69ea98354de29b102e3).

Comment: I had never use the `WITH...AS` approach. I will incorporate it into my work